# Render components with layout

Tags: reactjs

I have a layout where I get the user data and then a few pages.
what´s the correct way to use user data from the layout in the child components?

this is my Main component

```
const Main = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Route path="/" exact strict component={Homepage} />
            <Layout>
                <Route path="/friends" exact strict component={Friends} />
                <Route path="/family" exact strict component={Family} />
            </Layout>
        </Router>
    )
 }
```

this is the layout

```
const Layout (props) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({})
    useEffect(() => {
        getUser()
            .then(setUser)
            .catch(console.log('redirect to login page'))
    }, [])

    return(
        <div>
        <header>welcome {user.name}</header>
        <div>{props.children}</div>
        <footer>
            <NavLink to="/family">Family</Navlink>
            <NavLink to="/friends">Friends</Navlink>
        </footer>
    )
}

const Family = () => {return (<p>family</p>)}
const Friends = () => {return (<p>friends</p>)}
```

I´m not sure how to change the Main component to route those 2 urls to the components but using the Layout.

also this is rendering the layout evenn if I´m in the homepage
I´m wrapping Friends and Family in the Layout but it should be the other way around? how to avoid the render of the layout if im not in one of the pages that should use it?

Comment: You can use React ContextAPI to pass props down to the childrens https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: it's optional and you should select one than your use case, you can use props, context API and redux etc. but I advice you to use context API

Comment: cool. now I need to solve the routing. is rendering the layout even if I´m not in one of the pages that use the layout!

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**: Rendering the layout even if I´m in the homepage

**Solution**: This is because Layout component is not a part of route. You need to use `Switch`

**Issue** Passing user prop to `Family` and `Friends` from Layout component

**Solution**

You can render Friends and Family as renderProp to route by defining the routes inside Layout component and passing `user` as prop.

```
const Layout = props => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    getUser()
         .then(setUser)
         .catch(console.log('redirect to login page'))
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <header>welcome {user.name}</header>
      <Route path="/friends" exact strict render={(props) => <Friends {...props} user={user}/>} />
      <Route path="/family" exact strict render={(props) => <Family {...props} user={user}/>} />
      <footer>
        <NavLink to="/family">Family</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/friends">Friends</NavLink>
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
};

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact strict component={Homepage} />
        <Route component={Layout} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Solution 2:

Make use of context. In order to use context, ContextProvider needs to be in the hierarchy so route components need to be rendered directly inside the Layout component. In such case this can be used as below. Context is especially useful when your components have children and you need to use `user` down in the hierarchy

```
const UserContext = React.createContext(null);
const Friends = () => {
  const user = React.useContext(UserContext);
  return (
    <div>
      Friends<div>{user.name}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
const Family = props => {
  const user = React.useContext(UserContext);
  return (
    <div>
      Family<div>{user.name}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Layout = props => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    // getUser()
    //     .then(setUser)
    //     .catch(console.log('redirect to login page'))
    setUser({ name: "test name" });
  }, []);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
      <div>
        <header>welcome {user.name}</header>
        <Route path="/friends" exact strict component={Friends} />
        <Route path="/family" exact strict component={Family} />
        <footer>
          <NavLink to="/family">Family</NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/friends">Friends</NavLink>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `render prop`, pass in the user value from child(Layout) and call the children in Main component.

Also use a `Switch` component to avoid rendering the Layout component when you are on HomePage

**Main Component**

```js
const Main = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact strict component={Homepage} />
                <Layout>
                    {(user) => <>
                    <Route path="/friends" exact strict render={(props) => <Friends {...props} user={user} />} />
                    <Route path="/family" exact strict render={(props) => <Family {...props} user={user} />} />
                 </>}
                </Layout>
            </Switch>
        </>
    )
}
```

**Layout Component**

```js
const Layout = (props) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({})
    useEffect(() => {
        getUser()
            .then(setUser)
            .catch(console.log('redirect to login page'))
    }, []);

    return(
        <div>
            <header>welcome {user.name}</header>
            <div>{props.children(user)}</div>
            <footer>
                <NavLink to="/family">Family</Navlink>
                <NavLink to="/friends">Friends</Navlink>
            </footer>
        </div>)
}
```